# Applying filter and writing to a new column according to criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a VBA macro where I have multiple date fields in Excel and need to create each record under a particular stage based on the date value being null.

Suppose the value in column `B` is null then I need to update column `F` as `Pending at Stage A`, similarly, when the value in column `C` is null then Column `F` will be updated as `Pending at Stage B`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to filter!

```
Option Explicit

Function pendingAt(myRng As Range) As String

Dim actCell As Range
Dim actColumn As Integer

pendingAt = "all done!"

For Each actCell In myRng
    If actCell = "" Then
        actColumn = actCell.Column - 1
        pendingAt = "pending at " & Range("A1").Offset(0, actColumn).Value
        Exit For
    End If
Next actCell

End Function
```

[image]